# Python script for copying files from local folder and push it to BitBucket

Tags: python, git, file, validation, bitbucket

I have to write a python script for copying files from source folder to target folder and push it to BitBucket repository on a feature branch with File count and checksum logic where local files is equal to file pushed to BitBucket. Below code I'm referring...

```
import hashlib
import subprocess
from pybitbucket.auth import BasicAuthenticator
from pybitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket
from pybitbucket.repository import Repository

def calculate_checksum(file_path):
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(65536)
            if not data:
                break
            sha1.update(data)
    return sha1.hexdigest()

def count_files(folder_path):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        count += len(files)
    return count

def clone_files(source_folder, target_folder):
    subprocess.run(["cp", "-r", source_folder, target_folder])

def push_files_to_bitbucket(target_folder):
    subprocess.run(["git", "init"], cwd=target_folder)
    subprocess.run(["git", "config", "user.name", "Pandey,Prerna"], cwd=target_folder)
    subprocess.run(["git", "config", "user.email", "pandey_prerna@vanguard.com"], cwd=target_folder)
    subprocess.run(["git", "add", "."], cwd=target_folder)
    subprocess.run(["git", "commit", "-m", "Initial commit"], cwd=target_folder)
    remote_url = input("Enter the remote URL: ")
    subprocess.run(["git", "remote", "add", "origin", remote_url], cwd=target_folder)
    subprocess.run(["git", "push", "-u", "origin", "master"], cwd=target_folder)

folder_path = input("Enter the folder path: ")
file_count = count_files(folder_path)
print(f"Total number of files: {file_count}")
file_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    if root == folder_path:
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            checksum = calculate_checksum(file_path)
            print(f"File: {file_path}\nChecksum: {checksum}")
            file_list.append(file_path)

target_folder = input("Enter the target folder path: ")
clone_files(folder_path, target_folder)
push_files_to_bitbucket(target_folder)

bitbucket_username = input("Enter the Bitbucket username: ")
bitbucket_repo_name = input("Enter the Bitbucket Repository Name: ")
output = subprocess.run(["git", "ls-files"], capture_output=True, text=True, cwd=target_folder)
bitbucket_files = output.stdout.splitlines()

if sorted(file_list) == sorted(bitbucket_files):
    print("Files pushed to BitBucket are the same as local files.")
else:
    print("Files pushed to BitBucket are different from the local folder.")
```

Above Exact code I'm using.

Also, how can I change master branch to feature branch that is something I'm not getting at all

Let me know any corrections needed in this code so please let me know with specific logic.

Thanks in advance